# Strictly typed dynamic proxy to call dynamic object

Tags: c#, proxy

[GitHub](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/dynoproxy) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dynoproxy)

I would like to use DynamicObject derived types to execute  REST API/NodeJS module calls. It would also help to capture API shape in a strictly typed manner, so here comes an interface proxy which hides low level machinery allowing to do tricks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Call()
{
    dynamic c = new ExpandoObject();
    c.Add = (Func<int, int, int>)((a, b) => a + b);

    ICalculator proxy = Proxy.Create<ICalculator>(c);
    Assert.AreEqual(3, proxy.Add(1, 2));
}

public interface ICalculator
{
   int Add(int a, int b);
}
```

Library code is:

```
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
using Dynamitey;
using System;

namespace Dynoproxy
{
    public static class Proxy
    {
        public static T Create<T>(this object source) where T : class
        {
            var proxyGenerator = new ProxyGenerator();
            return proxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<T>(
                ProxyGenerationOptions.Default,
                new Interceptor(source));
        }

        class Interceptor : IInterceptor
        {
            public Interceptor(object target) => Target = target;
            object Target { get; }
            public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation) =>
                invocation.ReturnValue = Dynamic.InvokeMember(
                    Target, invocation.Method.Name, invocation.Arguments);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be very useful to see the associated `MethodInfo` instance while implementing source in the situation like this:

```
interface IMyWebApi
{
    [Description("GET orders/{0}")]
    Order GetOrder(int id); 
}

IWebApi api = Proxy.Create<IMyWebApi>(new RestApi("http://example.com/api"));
Order order = api.GetOrder(33);
```

So I made the proxy injecting it when `DescriptionAttribute` is provided:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Call()
{
    dynamic c = new ExpandoObject();
    c.Add = (Func<int, int, int>)((a, b) => a + b);
    c.Divide = (Func<MethodInfo, int, int, int>)((mi, a, b) => a / b);

    ICalculator proxy = Proxy.Create<ICalculator>(c);
    Assert.AreEqual(3, proxy.Add(1, 2));
    Assert.AreEqual(2, proxy.Divide(4, 2));
}

public interface ICalculator
{
    int Add(int a, int b);

    [Description]
    int Divide(int a, int b);
}
```

It should provide access to all interface method attributes and return types.

Updated `Interceptor` looks like this now:

```
class Interceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public Interceptor(object target) => Target = target;
    object Target { get; }
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation) =>
        invocation.ReturnValue = Dynamic.InvokeMember(
            Target,
            invocation.Method.Name,
            invocation.Method.IsDefined(typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) 
                ? invocation.Arguments.Prepend(invocation.Method).ToArray()
                : invocation.Arguments);
}
```